# Assigning Value to a Certain Index of a Variable List

Tags: python

This may be an elementary question.

Suppose I have several variables, x1, x2, x3.

I would like to assign a value to one of these variables, depending on the value of a certain index c.

Ideally, I would like to do something like
    [x1, x2, x3][c] = value
so that when c = 0, x1 is assigned a value, and when c = 1, x2 is assigned a value and so on.

But it doesn't seem that python is allowing me to do so.

Of course, I can do something like

```
if c = 0:
    x1 = value
elif c = 1:
    x2 = value
```

But this would be too long.

What should I do?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why don't you use a list to begin with?

Comment: On top of what Mark said, if for some reason you can't use a list, an `if-elif` chain is the correct solution.

Comment: Because x1, x2, and x3 are predefined by other people and are used elsewhere.

Comment: (There _are_ Python hacks you can use in some cases to simplify this sort of thing if the variables are actually named `x1`, `x2`, and so on, and you only want to assign them when `c` has the corresponding integer value, but these are the types of trick that make your code unreadable and exemplify how _not_ to write Python.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assign your variables to a list and then assign the values back using map, I suspect this isn't the best way to go about your application but without more information I can't really comment further.

Try this:

```
x1, x2, x3 = 2, 5, 10

var_list = [x1,x2,x3]

c = 1
var_list[c] = 42

x1, x2, x3 = map(lambda x:x,var_list)

print(x1, x2, x3)
```

Comment: This is not a bad idea given the constraints of the question…it might make a better answer if you explicitly include the OP's case of setting one of the variables based on the value of `c`.

Answer (score 0):

you could keep your variables in a dictionary, something like this:

```
vars = ['x0', 'x1', 'x2']

vars_value = {var: value for var, value in zip(vars, [None] * len(vars)}  # initialisation

vars_value[vars[c]] = <value>
```